# Unable to find the class for price - web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the price off the [website](https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/catalog/product-group/clinical-informatics/cardiology-informatics)

However, I'm having trouble locating the class type.

on this [website](https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3-advanced-planning-education)

we see that the price for this course is $5141.  When I check the source code the class for the price should be "field-items".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 
"https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3- 
advanced-planning-education"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(class_='field-items')

print(price)
```

However when I ran the code I got a description of the course instead of the price..not sure what I did wrong.  Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several "field-item even" classes on your webpage so you have to pick the one inside the good class. Here's the code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3-advanced-planning-education"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
section = soup.find(class_='field field-name-field-price field-type-number-decimal field-label-inline clearfix view-mode-full')
price = section.find(class_="field-item even").text
print(price)
```

And the result :

```
5141.00
```

Answer (score 3):

With bs4 4.7.1 + you can use :contains to isolate the appropriate preceeding tag then use adjacent sibling and descendant combinators to get to the target

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3-advanced-planning-education')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.field-label:contains("Price:") + div .field-item').text)
```

This

```
.field-label:contains("Price:")
```

looks for an element with class `field-label`, the `.` is a css class selector, which contains the text `Price:`. Then the `+` is an adjacent sibling combinator specifying to get the adjacent `div`. The  `.field-item` (space dot `field-item`) is a descendant combinator (the space) and class selector for a child of the adjacent `div` having class `field-item`. `select_one` returns the first match in the DOM for the css selector combination.

---

**Reading:**

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: Pseudo selectors are awesome. I'm an awe of this approach. Here is another `"section:has(> h2:contains('Price:')) .even"`

Comment: @SIM IKR... I actually miss bs4 when writing in other languages.

Comment: Ha ha, I know which language you talk about. I miss it too.

Comment: Gonna take me a while to understand the code, but thanks!

Comment: Any questions please ask

Answer (score 2):

To get the price you can try using ***[.select()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)*** which is precise and less error prone.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.learningconnection.philips.com/en/course/pinnacle%C2%B3-advanced-planning-education"

html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
price = soup.select_one("[class*='field-price'] .even").text
print(price)
```

Output:

```
5141.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the class I see, using Firefox inspector is : field-item even, it's where the text is:

```
<div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">5141.00</div></div>
```

But you need to change a little bit your code:

```
price = soup.find_all("div",{"class":'field-item even'})[2]
```

There are more than one "field-item even" labeled class, price is not the first one.